# AWS Lambda Cannot Access RDS via JDBC

Tags: amazon-web-services, java-8, aws-lambda

I have a test Lambda function setup using Java 8

So far I have

- given the Lambda function an execution role `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole`
- attached the Lambda function to the only VPC I have on my account and selected all subnets within the VPC so that it may access the
- my RDS instance in this case is open to the public, and I am able to access it via my Laptop (i.e. the Lambda code actually runs on remote hosts not inside the VPC)
- security group assigned to the `Lambda` is the most permissive possible (i.e all traffic on all CIDR block)

However, I am still unable to access my RDS instance when running the Lambda function on AWS (but the same code works on my laptop, when run from a `main()` function)

Sample Code

```
public class Application implements RequestHandler<Object, Boolean> {
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Application.class);
    public Boolean handleRequest(Object object, Context context) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            logger.info("Calling DriverManager.getConnection()");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://...endpoint...defaultdb",
                    "awsops",
                    "..."
            );
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            logger.info("Test Started!");
            ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT\n" +
                    "  last_name, COUNT(*)\n" +
                    "FROM\n" +
                    "  users\n" +
                    "GROUP BY\n" +
                    "  last_name\n" +
                    "HAVING COUNT(*) > 1");
            if (result.next()) {
                logger.info(result.getString("last_name"));
            }
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Can you please help me understand what I could be doing wrong?

The CloudWatch logs shows that the function hangs at `DriverManager.getConnection()`

Comment: The RDS instance has a security group. What inbound rules are on that SG? Also, there's a tutorial for this at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc-rds.html.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out my RDS was launched with an automatically created security group that literally just whitelisted my personal IP address ... so it feels like I was able to connect to it from 'anywhere'

I had to update the security group of my RDS instance to allow traffic from the subnets where the Lambda's virtual network interface could be coming from

Comment: You can remove all rules from the SG assigned to the Lambda function. There's no reason to assign anything to that SG, it accomplishes nothing. The reason a Lambda function has an SG applied to it is so you can reference that in other SG rules. In the SG assigned to the RDS instance, instead of listing all the IPs in your subnets you can smiply create a rule that allows inbound access from any members of a specific SG, in this case the SG assigned to your Lambda function. Editing the rule from the EC2 console's security group view, start typing "sg" to get a list of SGs to select from.